# Teradata-FastLoad, The request exceeds maximum length error

Tags: teradata

I am facing below error while fast loading CSV file.
Tried to find out the solution but with no luck.

Can you please help me ?
EDIT: Added sctipt file ...[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you show the script which causes this error?

Comment: what delimiter you are using?

Comment: @dnoeth, added script file, Bhavesh, using "," for comma delimited csv file ...

Comment: What's the defined length of the VarChars?

Comment: @dnoeth, it is ... in_Col1 (VARCHAR(200)), 
         in_Col2 (VARCHAR(200)), 
         in_Col3 (VARCHAR(50)), 
         in_Col4 (INTEGER), 
         in_Col5 (VARCHAR(50)),          
         FILE = CombineToLoad.csv;

Comment: @BhaveshGhodasara, using "," delimiter ...

Comment: Hmmmm, very strange, I don't have a clue what might cause this error, it's definitely less than 1MB source code.

Comment: @dnoeth, finally found the issue. We need to open fast load terminal, .LOGOFF, .QUIT & it works then ... Also, in some cases, not possible to release lock on the loading table. So better to drop that empty load table & associated error tables & restart loading ...

Answer (score 0):

***Following steps worked in my case ...***

> 1. Drop the error tables used in fast load script.
> 2. Recreate the table being loaded - `Release` table wont works everytime.
> 3. Last but not least, do not forget to mention the `.LOGOFF` at the end of fast load script.
> 4. Cure for above step is to `.LOGOFF` using `bteq` utility in `cmd` window.